# autoconf: use AS_INIT_GENERATED to generate a script in a subdirectory

Tags: autoconf, vpath

How can I use `AS_INIT_GENERATE` to generate a script that is not in the same directory as the `configure` script, in particular so that VPATH builds will be honoured?

For example, for a `configure.ac` file containing

```
AC_PREREQ([2.68])
AC_INIT([example],[0.1])
AS_INIT_GENERATED([src/file.sh]) || AS_EXIT
AC_OUTPUT
```

running the commands

```
~ $ autoreconf .
~ $ mkdir build && cd build
~/build $ ../configure
```

results in the error message

```
../configure: line 1648: src/file.sh: No such file or directory
../configure: line 1655: src/file.sh: No such file or directory
```

I guess I'd have to make sure that the `src` directory exists before I call `AS_INIT_GENERATE` to create `src/file.sh`, or maybe I'm doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.68])
AC_INIT([example],[0.1])
test -d src || AS_MKDIR_P([src]) dnl <----- Create 'src' if it doesn't exist.
AS_INIT_GENERATED([src/file.sh]) || AS_EXIT
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Yeah, creating the `src` directory explicitly seems to be the answer. Although, isn't the test for the existence of `src` redundant? Doesn't `mkdir -p` exit silently if the directory already exists?

Comment: On my machine, yes it is silent. I'm not 100% sure why I made the check. Just to be thorough, I suppose.